# Dense stratification of a separable Hilbert space

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, ds.dynamical-systems, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, tauberian-theorems

Let $\{X_i\}_{i \in \mathbb{N}} $ be a sequence of $n$-dimensional linear subspaces of the separable Hilbert space $H$ and let $\{\phi_i\}_{i \in I}$ be a sequence of continuous injective linear maps from $H$ to itself such that:

- $\phi_i(X_i)=X_{i+1}$,
- $X_i\cap X_j =\{0\}$ if $i\neq j$.

Is there a general criteria under which 
$
X := \cup_{i \in \mathbb{N}} X_i,
$
is dense in $H$?

**Note 1:**
*I don't want to assume that $\phi_i =\phi^i$ where $\phi$ is a [hypercyclic operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypercyclic_operator) and $X_0$ contains a hypercylic vector.  Since, typically, those objects can rarely be made explicit and rely on existence type results.*

**Vague Intuition**
I expect some type of Wiener-Tauberian-like theorem where one looses the ability to take the span but somehow it is generated by iterations of $\phi$...

WLOG *(if it helps)*, we may assume that $H=L^2(\mathbb{R})$.

Comment: But then if $n=1$ you want $X_0$ to contain a supercyclic vector

Comment: Sure, but if n is large then the condition strictly relaxes

Comment: May be of interest: https://arxiv.org/abs/1205.3575

Comment: Yes, but this doesn't give me an explicit criterion I can check to verify if $X_0$ has this property also..